# Manipulating Prolog code output

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to run code on this page: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/clpfd_queens.pl in swipl on a Linux terminal.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_queens(N, Qs) :-
    length(Qs, N),
    Qs ins 1..N,
    safe_queens(Qs).

safe_queens([]).
safe_queens([Q|Qs]) :-
    safe_queens(Qs, Q, 1),
    safe_queens(Qs).

safe_queens([], _, _).
safe_queens([Q|Qs], Q0, D0) :-
    Q0 #\= Q,
    abs(Q0 - Q) #\= D0,
    D1 #= D0 + 1,
    safe_queens(Qs, Q0, D1).
```

Following command works:

```
?- n_queens(4, Qs), labeling([ff], Qs).
```

But not just `n_queens(4, Qs)`:

```
?- n_queens(4, Qs).
Qs = [_G1470, _G1473, _G1476, _G1479],
_G1470 in 1..4,
abs(_G1470-_G1479)#\=3,
_G1470#\=_G1479,
abs(_G1470-_G1476)#\=2,
_G1470#\=_G1476,
abs(_G1470-_G1473)#\=1,
_G1470#\=_G1473,
_G1479 in 1..4,
abs(_G1476-_G1479)#\=1,
_G1476#\=_G1479,
abs(_G1473-_G1479)#\=2,
_G1473#\=_G1479,
_G1476 in 1..4,
abs(_G1473-_G1476)#\=1,
_G1473#\=_G1476,
_G1473 in 1..4.
```

Why is `labeling` part needed here? Can one get proper output without `labeling` part?

For larger numbers, one gets only initial  part of the solution:

```
?- n_queens(20, Qs), labeling([ff], Qs).
Qs = [1, 3, 5, 14, 17, 4, 16, 7, 12|...] ;
Qs = [1, 3, 5, 18, 16, 4, 10, 7, 14|...] ;
...
```

How can one get full list output for larger numbers? Also, how can one get all numbers together, without having to press spacebar for each solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, the idea of `n_queens` is to *construct* a constraint programming problem. `labelling` does the real relaxation and branching and searches for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n_queens/2` does **not** solves the *N*-queens problem for *N* queens: it *constructs* the constraint programming problem: it constructs *N* variables (the columns of the queens), and adds constraints between these queens: for instance that two queens can not be placed on the same row, nor on the same diagonal. We see this if we rewrite the problem output to more convenient output:

```
A in 1..4,
abs(A-D)#\=3,
A#\=D,
abs(A-C)#\=2,
A#\=C,
abs(A-B)#\=1,
A#\=B,
D in 1..4,
abs(C-D)#\=1,
C#\=D,
abs(B-D)#\=2,
B#\=D,
C in 1..4,
abs(B-C)#\=1,
B#\=C,
B in 1..4.
```

So we see four queens (`A`, `B`, `C` and `D`). Each of the queens should be in the domain `1..4`, furthermore we see non equal constraints like `A #\= D` to prevent the first queen `A` sharing a column with the last queen `D`. We finally see constraints like `abs(A-C) #\= 2` to prevent the first queen `A` and the third queen `C` to differ two columns (diagnal attack).

Next `labeling/2` will actually **solve** the problem: it performs relaxation (reducing the domains) as well as branching (picking a value or a subrange of values for variables) and backtracking in case the constraints fail. It will continue until it finds a solution, and we can use Prolog's backtracking mechanism to let `labeling/2` come up with more solutions.

`labeling` thus is given a list of variables and aims to *label* them: assign them a value out of the range such that all constraints are satisfied.

Therefore the problem construction part is usually very fast compared to the actually solving part: it is easy to generate *O(N)* variables and *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* constraints, but it can take an exponential amount of time *O(D<sup>N</sup>)* to come up with a solution satisfying all constraints.

> Also, how can one get all numbers together, without having to press spacebar for each solution?

You can use the meta-predicate `findall/3` for that:

```
all_n_queens(N,LL) :-
    findall(L,(n_queens(N,L), labeling([ff], L)),LL).
```

Which generates:

```
?- all_n_queens(5,LL).
LL = [[1, 3, 5, 2, 4], [1, 4, 2, 5, 3], [2, 4, 1, 3, 5], [2, 5, 3, 1, 4], [3, 1, 4, 2|...], [3, 5, 2|...], [4, 1|...], [4|...], [...|...]|...].
```

> How can one get full list output for larger numbers?

You can set the `answer_write_options` flag:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)]).
true.

?- all_n_queens(5,LL).
LL = [[1,3,5,2,4],[1,4,2,5,3],[2,4,1,3,5],[2,5,3,1,4],[3,1,4,2,5],[3,5,2,4,1],[4,1,3,5,2],[4,2,5,3,1],[5,2,4,1,3],[5,3,1,4,2]].
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. How come there is no use of 'labeling' in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863531/n-queens-problem-how-far-can-we-go

Comment: @rnso: there is. At the end of the `queens/2` predicate it calls `labeling([ffc],L).`. Of course you can call `labeling` in the predicate that constructs it.

Comment: I should have checked more carefully.

Comment: Is solution in this question essentially same as one on the other page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863531/n-queens-problem-how-far-can-we-go

Comment: @rnso: yes the difference is that the constraints in this question look like `abs(X-Y) #\= 2`, etc. whereas in the other question, it looks like `X #\= Y-2` and `X #\= Y+2`.